# Android - Update custom view from asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a custom view class

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

//drawing path
private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0x00660000;

...
public void printPoint(Point p, Boolean b){
    if(p != null){
        Paint testePaint = new Paint();
        testePaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        testePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        testePaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
        testePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        testePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        testePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        if(b){
            testePaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        }else{
            testePaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        }
        drawCanvas.drawPoint(p.x, p.y, testePaint);
    }
}

public void printPath(){
    if(paths.size() > 0){
        Path testePath = new Path();

        Paint testePaint = new Paint();
        testePaint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
        testePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        testePaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
        testePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        testePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        testePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        testePath = paths.remove(0);

        drawCanvas.drawPath(testePath, testePaint);
    }
}
}
```

add the view to the layout and load it into MainActivity using

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    //TCP COM
    private TcpClient mTcpClient;

    //
    private DrawingView drawView;
    private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn, eraseBtn, newBtn;

    private float smallBrush, mediumBrush, largeBrush;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
        currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));

        drawView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
        drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);

....
}
```

when I click a button I call the following function

```
public void updateView(Linha l){
    Log.d("TCP","updateView()");
    if(l.getEscreve() == true){
        drawView.printPath();
    }
    drawView.printPoint(l.getPonto(),l.getEscreve());
}
```

and it works but when I call it from `onProgressUpdate` from an asynctask I can only see the draws on the view if I click again on the button.

Answer (score 0):

hmm I don't think you should be updating UI on a different thread. Instead you override onDraw in your custom view, and from your asynctask do postInvalidate to trigger onDraw being called on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add `invalidate();` after drawPath and drawPoint resolved the problem :)